# Linq from List<T> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a List and a dataGridView1 and I'm trying to do this:

```
var result = from s in sessions
             where s.ID > 0
             select s;
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

It compiles fine, nothing shows in the DataGridView and no exceptions.

If I however set `dataGridView1.DataSource = sessions;` it shows everything.

Comment: Are there session with an id larger then 0? What if you debug you're code and look at result.ToList()?

Comment: Yes and even if I remove the where clause nothing changes. result.ToList() doesn't change anything either.

Comment: did you try via `BindingSource`?

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen - Do you do dataGridView1.DataBind() after setting the datasource?

Comment: It eventually worked with ToList() when I fixed an error somewhere else. Now I also convert the result list to a DataTable to enable sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
var result = from s in sessions
             where s.ID > 0
             select s;
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

In fact because of [linq deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), your linq query doesn't execute until you fetch some data.

If you add ToList and you see nothing, it means that there is no result and nothing goes wrong, just check your `result.ToList()` in watch window in debug mode, if there isn't any result it's OK, but if you see some result may be you should refresh your dataGridView or rebind it.

Comment: @WouterdeKort my answer for question is right, and comment is not part of question (and I didn't see that) may be he has another problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may do the trick:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a scenario in which using dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList(); works but using result directly doesn't work. It seems that a DataGridView isn't designed to directly bind to an IEnumerable (the result of a Linq statement).

Comment: In fact when you create query (e.g result in this case) you didn't execute it, linq will be postpone the execution of linq query to time you want fetch it, and what is your `result` variable? It's just query not enumerable object, e.g if you debug this in big query on big db, you will be see breakpoint will be passed very fast, but if you add `.ToList()` it works fast enough. see [linq deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: Logical explanation, that's what I wanted to convey. IQueryable derives from IEnumerable and that's why I called it IEnumerable. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)

Comment: This part of your answer:"It seems that a DataGridView isn't designed to directly bind to an IEnumerable" is not correct. again I should to say what returned is not executed IEnumerable, read my link. In fact is just compiled query, not really IQueryable, it should be executed.